# sql, cout number of childrens per each campaigns ancestry

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ancestry

how to count in sql number of children per name in ancestry like tree structure

```
ID | NAME                    | PATH
100 | Electronics & Computers | /100
101 | Games                   | /100/101
102 | Xbox360                 | /100/101/102
103 | PS4                     | /100/101/103
```

so i should have something like

```
100 | 3
101 | 2
102 | 0
103 | 0
```

thanks much for help

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that uses a self join and aggregation:

```
select t.id, count(t2.id)
from t left join
     t t2
     on t2.path like concat(t.path, '/%')
group by t.id;
```

Comment: so t and t2 are 2 tables ?, I mean my example with name and path is in same table

Comment: works great only there is one small issue that first element has path nil and it's not counting for him but maybe i will be able to sort it out

Comment: @urbanczykd . . . would `+ 1` fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id,
        (SELECT count(B.id) FROM `tablename` B where path like CONCAT('%/', A.id, '%' ) and B.id != A.id) count
    FROM `tablename` A
```

Try this one. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51b7b/1

Comment: same issue sorry forgot to mention that first entry has path = nil